# AGM MAP | Adding marker just in drawn Polygon

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

**Issue description**
I use [**AGM_MAP**](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps) library for angular website that contains a map to able users select an address on the map for getting theirs orders.

**Current behavior**
My problem is when i add a polygon on the map, the marker can't be on that area which shows with polygon. But i can add the marker outside the polygon.

**Expected/desired behavior**
In the end i need add a marker just on that area which shows with polygon.

Html codes:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="14" (mapClick)="addMarker($event)">
  <agm-polygon [paths]="latlngBounds">
  </agm-polygon>
  <agm-marker *ngIf="isShowMarker" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [label]="'M'">
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

[image: screenshot from 2018-02-26 12-47-40]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed for adding markers on the polygon shapes we must set clickable attribute to false like below:

```
<agm-polygon [paths]="paths" [clickable]="false">
</agm-polygon>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-hbskrd) sample